# Annotate Image based on pixel position

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, coordinates, grids

I have an image that I am calling inside a table via Ti*k*Z.

The position I am trying to mark in this image is stored in my DB via a web application which is capturing the co-ordinates in (x,y) based on pixels, like (254,145). But here in my LaTeX code the positions are being marked in 1,2,3,4,...,10.

How do I mark the position based on pixels?
How do I start my position (0,0) from the top left rather than bottom left?

[image: Image with annotation]

```
{\begin{tikzpicture} \node [
       above right,
       inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=11.535833333cm, height=10.900833333cm]{adeck.png}};
   \begin{scope} %[
  x={($0.1*(image.south east)$)},
  y={($0.1*(image.north west)$)}]
% Grid
\draw[lightgray,step=1] (image.south west) grid (image.north east);
 
% Axes' labels
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,10} { \node [above] at (\x,0) {\x}; }
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,10} { \node [right] at (0,\y) {\y};}
    
   % Labels
   \node[circle,fill=green] at (6.0153020833,4.6302083333,){\small };
    
   \end{scope}
   \end{tikzpicture}}
```

Comment: I do not think that pixel-based positioning is helpful. I would stick with more meaningful inits such as mm, cm, or inch.

Comment: In your code, you already define the image size in inch (`width=11.535833333cm, height=10.900833333cm`). How did you create the code? Is it a result of a code export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually just a matter of calculation. You know the size of your image in pixels (the one I used is 192 × 108 pixels) and you know the pixel-based coordinate of the positon of the mark. You further set the x and y values of your tikzpicture to 0.1 × the width (or heigth) of your image.

Given this, it is quite simple to attach a node at a certain pixel-based coordinate, because the x and y values are then just 10 × <pixel-based coordinate x (or y) value> : <pixel-based image width (or height)>. You can use the `calc` library to do these calculations on the fly.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 

\node[inner sep=0, anchor=south west] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=17.42cm, height=9.8cm]{example-1.png}};
   
\begin{scope}[
    x={($0.1*(image.south east)$)},
    y={($0.1*(image.north west)$)}
]

% Grid
\draw[lightgray,step=1] (image.south west) grid (image.north east);

% Axes' labels
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,10} { \node [below] at (\x,0) {\x}; }
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,10} { \node [left] at (0,\y) {\y}; }

% Labels
\node[circle,fill=green] at ({10*139/192},{10*77/108}) {};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Inaccuracy is due to rounding errors.

If you want to anchor it on the top, just flip the relevant things (the y value of the pixel-based coordinate should then also adhere to this logic, of course):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 

\node[inner sep=0, anchor=north west] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=17.42cm, height=9.8cm]{example-1.png}};
   
\begin{scope}[
    x={($0.1*(image.north east)$)},
    y={($0.1*(image.south west)$)}
]

% Grid
\draw[lightgray, xstep=1, ystep=-1] (image.south west) grid (image.north east);

% Axes' labels
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,10} { \node [above] at (\x,0) {\x}; }
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,10} { \node [left] at (0,\y) {\y}; }

% Labels
\node[circle,fill=green] at ({10*139/192},{10*30/108}) {};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There is one thing to take care of: Because we flip the y values of the `tikzpicture`, we need to adjust the options of the grid accordingly: `xstep=1, ystep=-1`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, this worked perfectly like a charm.